# Radio buttons and labels on same line, each radio set on separate lines - css only

Tags: html, css

I am trying to solve the problem of having radio buttons + labels be on separate lines.
I have read various solutions and they do not fit my requirements.

1. I cannot nest the radio and label in its own block element.  That is the easy answer but it breaks the "radio tabbing", so cannot be done.
2. I cannot use javascript, or this would be easy.  All of this is intended to go into the `<noscripts>...</noscripts>` portion of the page.
3. I can add additional block elements into the structure as needed (i.e. div.radioalign elements below), but again - as per 1 // cannot nest the radio and label (unless there is a different method to achieve radio tabbing without javascript).
4. Must be responsive (hence the use of flex/wrap instead of position:absolute).

The structure of my html is as follows:

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="radioalign"></div>
   <input type="radio" class="radiobtn" name="contentselector" id="contentradio1">
   <label for="contentradio1" class="radiolbl">Content Box 1</label>
   <div class="contentbox">The contents of box 1, including a form, some pictures, etc...</div>
   <div class="radioalign"></div>
   <input type="radio" class="radiobtn" name="contentselector" id="contentradio2">
   <label for="contentradio2" class="radiolbl">Content Box 2</label>
   <div class="contentbox">The contents of box 2, including a different form, some different pictures, etc...</div>
</div>
```

My CSS is:

```
.container {
   display: flex;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.radioalign {
   width: 0px;
}

.radiobtn {
   margin-left: 10px;
}

.radiolbl {
   // Need to make this element force a line break somehow...
}

.radiobtn:checked+.radiolbl+.contentbox {
   display: block;
}

.contentbox {
   order: 999;
   display: none;
}
```

Workarounds that I have used don't look quite right.
i.e. forcing the 2nd radio on the next line due to margin/width:

```
.radiobtn {
   margin-right: 10%;
}

.radiolbl {
   width: 85%;
}
```

Below is an ASCII-art of the desired page:

```
o Content Box 1
o Content Box 2
|------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|                                                                        |
| Content Box 1 or 2 depending on radio selection                        |
|                                                                        |
|------------------------------------------------------------------------|
```

Below is an ASCII-art of the current state of the page:

```
o Content Box 1  o Content Box 2 <--- on the same line
|------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|                                                                        |
| Content Box 1 or 2 depending on radio selection                        |
|                                                                        |
|------------------------------------------------------------------------|
```

Comment: How about flex-direction:column ? I mean for the child div 'radioalign'

Comment: What do you mean?  How would flex-direction solve this?

Comment: Please specify clearly what do you want to accomplish.

Comment: I've added ascii art to clarify.

Comment: what is `<div class="radioalign">` for?

Comment: To add padding in front of the radio button for certain media types.  i.e. .radioalign { width: 30%; } @media (max-width: 500px) { .radioalign: { width: 0px; } } - it's its own separate element so the effective left-padding is 30% + 10px (margin-left on radiobtn is 10px).

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `display: flex` and `flex-wrap` in your container class and place a `<br />` after your radio label

then make a different class for your radio label and its content to display the desired content that goes with your specific radio button.

please see snippet below

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>

    <style>
        
        .radioalign {
        width: 0;
        }

        .radiobtn:checked+.radiolbl1 ~ .box1 {
            display: block;
        }
        .radiobtn:checked+.radiolbl2 ~ .box2 {
            display: block;
        }

        .contentbox {
            order: 999;
            display: none;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        
        <input type="radio" class="radiobtn" name="contentselector" id="contentradio1">
        <label for="contentradio1" class="radiolbl1">Content Box 1</label>
        <br />
        <input type="radio" class="radiobtn" name="contentselector" id="contentradio2">
        <label for="contentradio1" class="radiolbl2">Content Box 2</label>
        
        <div class="contentbox box1">this is content 1</div>
        <div class="contentbox box2">this is content 2</div>
     </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Wrapping the radio causes this to break: ```.radiobtn:checked+.radiolbl+.contentbox {
          display: block;
        }```  So I explicitly stated in my question that we cannot nest the radio in another block structure.

Comment: OK change your code to the following: ```<div class="contentbox">This is the content of box 1</div>``` and ```<div class="contentbox">This is the content of box 2</div>```.  Then click Run code snippet.  When you select the first radio, you should see "This is the content of box 1" and when you select the second radio, you should see "This is the content of box 2".  Since the ```display:block``` gets broken, you see neither.

Comment: if we cant nest the radio in another block structure, we just need to remove the `display: flex` and `flex-wrap` in the container class

Comment: Can you test your solution please?  How will removing ```display: flex``` solve this problem?  I updated my code in the question so you can test it.

Comment: And you will see that it has changed the position of contentbox.  When you click radio1, contentbox appears in the middle.  The display:flex + order:999 makes it so that contentbox is always below all radio buttons.  Hence cannot remove display:flex.